# Terminologies on left and right ideal related properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

> Definition
>
> Let $R$ be an rng. (A ring possibly without a unity)
>
> Then, $R$ is **left-Artinian** if it satisfies DCC for left ideals, and $R$ is **right-Artinian** if it satisfies DCC for right ideals.

Say, $R$ ia an rng satisfying DCC for two-sided ideals. Then, it may be neither left-Artinian nor right-Artinian. What would this rng be called? Is this rng meaningless in some sense?

When people say an rng is Artinian, they mean it is both left and right Artinian, not the above case.

All terminologies on ideals that I know, are defined in the same way as Artinian rng. (e.g. Artinian, Noetherian, semisimple etc) What would ideals with those properties on two-sided ideals be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard naming convention for this, and indeed it's rare to see conditions defined in terms of the twosided ideals.

The exceptions that came to mind for me were:

1. Simple rings
2. Fully prime rings (every proper twosided ideal is prime)
3. Fully semiprime rings (every twosided ideal is semiprime)

For the specific topic of chain conditions on twosided ideals, I would recommend something straightforward like "ACC on (twosided) ideals."